# Why do an initial ERC-20 offering on a testnet instead of Mainnnet?

Tags: erc-20, testnets, ico, mainnet

Why would someone launch an ICO to an Ethereum network other than Mainnet, i.e. testnets? Are there any technical or philosophical reasons why someone would not choose Mainnet to launch a new ERC-20 token, but instead Kovan, Ropsten, Rinkeby, Goerli etc? Would the reasons be purely experimental for each one of these alternatives, or are they different in someway for launches? If experimental for all, then does that mean the end intention is to eventually do an official launch on Mainnet after trying the testnets, or are there ERC-20s that have fluorished entirely outside of Mainnet?